# cannot make relation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a relation table in table pelatih and table absen. But when I try to make  a relation id_pelatih it always input number "3".

This is the controller:

```
function absen()
    {
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
        $nim = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $id_user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $id_pelatih = $id_pelatih;

        $this->load->model('mabsensi');
        $data = array(
            'id_pelatih'    => $this->mlogin->get_data_pelatih_by_id_user($id_user)->id_pelatih,
            'nim'           => $nim,
            'tanggal'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'keterangan'    => 'Hadir'
        );

        $this->mabsensi->insert_absensi($data);

        redirect($this->agent->referrer());
    }
```

This is the model

```
    function get_data_pelatih_by_id_user($id_user)
    {
        $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('pelatih as a, user as u')
            ->where('a.id_user = u.id_user')
            ->limit(1);
        return $this->db->get()->row();
    }
```

Please tell me how to solved this.

Comment: did u try with multiple session ??

Answer (score 1):

Your model isn't correct. If you want to get data from different tables you should use JOIN. And you have to say which record you need. So, add a WHERE statement to your query.

```
function get_data_pelatih_by_id_user($id_user)
{
     $this->db->SELECT('*')
              ->FROM('user')
              ->WHERE('id_user', $id_user) // your parameter, you did not use it
              ->JOIN('pelatih', 'pelatih.id_user = user.id_user');

     return $this->db->get();
}
```

Also have a look at the documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: id_user is ambigous. how?

Comment: i always try and in my table id_pelatih is null. how ?

Comment: i haven't error. i try relation table pelatih and table absen use id_pelatih. but id_pelatih in table absen is null. how?

Comment: Where is id_pelatih null? In the query result?

Comment: in table absen. A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$id_pelatih

Filename: pelatih/absensi.php

Line Number: 77

array(4) { ["id_pelatih"]=> NULL ["nim"]=> string(6) "312892" ["tanggal"]=> string(19) "2014-05-26 14:40:33" ["keterangan"]=> string(5) "Hadir" }

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your problem. I don't even know exactly what you want. Your table names are incomprehensible for me. Have you read the CodeIgniter documentation? And have you searched on Google?